# Which way is correct "один/одна"

Tags: множественное-число

In the following sentence which way would be correct?

> Один/одна из тех людей, которые никогда не откажут в помощи - это наш врач.

The singular of **люди** is **человек** which is male. But what if the aforementioned doctor is a female?

Comment: in colloquial speech "наша врач" is also accepted.

Comment: Looks like somebody went through and downvoted every single answer to this question.  I'm interested to know what the reason for this was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sentence as you wrote it, when you refer to some generic doctor, you will use *один* (masculine) version in a sentence like this:

> Один из тех людей, которые никогда не откажут в помощи - это наш врач.

The main reason for it is not that the singular of *люди* is *человек* (which is masculine), but that *врач* is masculine (as a word, not a person).  This is why you use *наш* with it.  You could say

> Одна из тех людей, которые никогда не откажут в помощи - это наша врач.

In this case you are referring to a specific doctor - and in that case using *одна* would be grammatically correct: if you are talking about a specific female doctor in a specific group of people.  Another example would be

> Одна из этих людей - наша врач.

However in a general conversation you would use word *один*.

Comment: Care to explain why the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Well, you use "врач", and it's male. So, You should use "один" here:

```
Один из тех людей, которые никогда не откажут в помощи - это наш врач.
```

But if noun whould be female, you should use female form. For example:

```
Одна их тех людей, которые никогда не откажут в помощи -- это наша мать.
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use 'Один из тех людей, которые никогда не откажут в помощи - это наш врач,' because врач means a male doctor so you should use Один.

Comment: _Врач_ doesn't necessarily mean a male doctor.  A female doctor is also _врач_.